# Send parameter microservices. Jhipster 4.6.2

Tags: angular, jhipster

I do not get my parameter from the front to back, in the Angular Service if a value is correctly loaded in:
If embarno does not reach the backend, this same code works correctly in a monopoly application of Jhipster 4.4.1.
Now I have not migrated and it is in a microservice of version 4.6.2, I do not know if it has changed the syntax of sending parameters.

Controller:

```
  this.contactoService.byCliente(this.cliente.id).subscribe(
            result => { this.contactos = result; },
            error => { console.debug(error); });
```

Service:

```
byCliente(clienteId?: any): Observable<Contacto[]> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('clienteId', clienteId);
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl + "/bycliente", { search: params }).map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
    });
}
```

Back(Microservice):

```
 @GetMapping("/contactos/bycliente")
 @Timed
 public ResponseEntity<List<ContactoDTO>> getAllContactosByCliente(@RequestParam String clienteId) {
   log.debug("REST request to get a page of Contactos");
   List<ContactoDTO> list = contactoService.findContactosByCliente(clienteId);
   return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

Error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: Required String parameter 'clienteId' is not present org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'clienteId' is not present
```

Comment: I had renamed it for the privacy question, it's already fixed.

Comment: There are not enough details to get help. What about a dump of the HTTP the request as sent by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the parameter directly in the url when calling the api in your Service :

```
byCliente(clienteId?: any): Observable<Contacto[]> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl + "/bycliente?clienteId="+clienteId).map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
    });
}
```